# C# RichTextBox Displaying Random Format

Tags: serial-port, richtextbox

I have an RS232 communication app with 2 RichTextBox forms. One form is for logging "Outgoing" messages and the other form is for recieving "Incoming" messages from the port. I've used the same syntax for logging messages but for some reason I get random formats in my "Incoming" window (reading from the port).

Is there a way to get the "Incoming" box to display each incoming response byte[] on a new line? I am using a hyper-terminal so anything I send out should come back immediately through the same port.

*Both RTB windows use the following log method*

```
        private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, string msgOut)
    {
        rtbOutgoing.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            rtbOutgoing.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            rtbOutgoing.SelectionFont = new Font(rtbOutgoing.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            rtbOutgoing.SelectionColor = LogMsgTypeColor[(int)msgtype];
            rtbOutgoing.AppendText(msgOut);
            rtbOutgoing.ScrollToCaret();
        }));
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of Output Windows]

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls Log()?

Comment: 'LogOutgoing(LogMsgType.Outgoing, "Short Address" + i.ToString() + "\n");'

Comment: I don't see the string "Short Address" anywhere in your output. Are you sure this is the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you should be able to try something like this. We're going to change what i.ToString() is outputting so that it's converted to newline delimited data instead of space-delimited:

Try this:

```
LogOutgoing(LogMsgType.Outgoing, "Short Address" + i.ToString().Replace(" ", "\n") + "\n");
```

That'll change all spaces into "\n" before the string is sent to the log() function.